# Moving window "osk" in Qt application

Tags: qt, process, move

I'm programming a tactile application in Qt and I use the virtual keyboard "osk" to permit the user to type text.
I launch the "osk"  with this code

```
QProcess process;
process.start("osk.exe");
```

The problem I have is that the size of my app is limited, so I would like to move the keyboard  in order to it is centered in my app. 
Can I move it as I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Win32 API for that:

```
#include "windows.h"


HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, L"On-Screen Keyboard");
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
MoveWindow(hwnd, 100, 100, rc.right-rc.left, rc.bottom-rc.top, true);
```

This will move the window to (100,100) location.